# Prove that a sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that $\{V_k\}$ is convergent? I tried to build a general term for $V_k$ but I don't get to anything.

Let $\{V_k\}$, $\{\lambda_k\}$, $\{B_k\}$ be non negative sequences of real numbers that satisfy

\begin{equation*}
V_k \le (1+\lambda_k)V_{k-1} + B_k
\end{equation*}

where $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty B_k < \infty$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k < \infty$.

Prove that $\{V_k\}$ is convergent.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What space do the sequence elements lie in?  For example, is the space Cauchy complete?

Comment: @EnjoysMath the real numbers.

Comment: Try to prove the boundedness of $(V_k)$ [maybe this is the hardest part]

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: By induction, one can show
\begin{align}
V_k-V_{k-1} \leq&\ \lambda_k\prod^{k-1}_{i=2}(1+\lambda_i)V_1+\left(B_k+\lambda_kB_{k-1}+\ldots +\lambda_k\prod^{k-1}_{i=2}(1+\lambda_i)B_1\right)\\
\leq&\ \lambda_k \left\{e^{-\lambda}(V_1+\lambda B) \right\}+B_k.
\end{align}
where $\lambda = \sum \lambda_i$ and $B= \sum B_i$. Then we see that
\begin{align}
V_n-V_m=\sum^n_{k=m+1} (V_k-V_{k-1}) \leq e^{-\lambda}(V_1+\lambda B) \left(\sum^n_{k=m+1}\lambda_k\right) + \left(\sum^n_{k=m+1}B_k\right)
\end{align}
which shows that the sequence is Cauchy. Hence $\{V_k\}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that for $n\geq m\geq 1$,
$$V_n-V_m=\sum_{k=m+1}^n(V_k-V_{k-1}) \le \sum_{k=m+1}^n \lambda_kV_{k-1} + \sum_{k=m+1}^nB_k$$
Hence if we show that $(V_n)_n$ is bounded by some non-negative constant $M$ then 
$$|V_n-V_m|=|\sum_{k=m+1}^n(V_k-V_{k-1})| \le M\sum_{k=m+1}^n \lambda_k + \sum_{k=m+1}^nB_k$$
which implies that $(V_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k < \infty$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty B_k < \infty$.